# Open-source p2p videoconferencing in Flash or Java?

Tags: java, flash, p2p, voip, video-conferencing

I want to build a community website with videoconferencing functionality integrated. I would prefer to provide this from within the browser, so I'm looking for a Java- or Flash-based solution.

Also, it would be nice to spare bandwidth by having the clients stream their audio and video data without using a central server (like the way Skype works, for example).

Is there a reasonably mature open-source project that meets these criteria?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When doing Voice over IP, UDP is preferred, and web browser plugins usually lacks support for UDP and P2P-connections.

But there is a solution. You have to use Adobe Flash Player 10 and the [Adobe Stratus](http://labs.adobe.com/technologies/stratus/) for this. This is actually what [Chatroulette](http://www.chatroulette.com/) is using for P2P streamed video chat.

Answer (score 1):

Take it from someone who found out the hard way: Java's support for video playback is pisspoor.  They keep promising a new, fantastic video playback system, but meanwhile we are STILL stuck with Java Media Framework, the platform-limited, MPEG-4 incompatible mess.

Your alternatives are Quicktime for Java and systems wrapping MPlayer/VLC/etc.  None of those are really options for a browser.

Much as I hate Adobe and the evils of Flash site design, Flash is far and away your best option.

Answer (score 1):

See the [Xuggler](http://www.xuggle.com/xuggler) library -- it includes code for playing back video (well, sample code) in the com.xuggle.mediatool.IMediaVieer object.